# MVC5 + Entity Framework + Form + Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Eu tenho uma aplicação onde existe uma entidade central e vários outros cadastros auxiliares, como Status, Formato, Tipo, etc. Todas essas entidades auxiliares possuem apenas 2 campos: Nome e Status (booleano, informando se está ativo ou não). Como são entidades muito simples, eu não gostaria de criar uma tela para cada uma. Além disso, gostaria de permitir que o usuário, ao cadastrar um registro da entidade principal, pudesse fazer manutenções nessas entidades auxiliares (exclusão, inclusão, edição...).

Porém, quando eu trabalho com PartialViews e formulários, tenho um problema, pois a tela é carregada novamente, para validações no backend e, quando é retornado, a tela é recarregada, perdendo o estado de modais abertos e tudo mais.

Como fazer esse tipo de manutenção com modais? Gostaria que fossem abertos 2 modais: um de listagem e outro de edição/inserção.

Campo do formulário com botão para CRUD de Formatos
[image: Campo do formulário com botão para CRUD de Formatos]

Listagem de Formatos
[image: Listagem de Formatos]

Formulário com edição/inserção de Formatos
[image: Formulário com edição/inserção de Formatos]

Quando clico no botão Criar, no formulário dentro do modal, a tela é redirecionada e perco todo o estado do formulário principal e modais abertos.

Comment: Inlua o código das suas views e controller só coma imagem não dá para responder. Mas na validação backend você precisa popular esses componentes indicando qual valor havia sido selecionado.

Comment: Basicamente, são partialviews (para os formulários auxiliares) dentro de modais, em um formulário principal (View). Não tem muito segredo e estou começando o código agora. Fiz apenas um teste, adicionando um erro no ModelState e, quando a validação retorna o resultado, a tela é redirecionada para a action da partialview.

Comment: Eu sei, mas o código é mais útil que as imagens.

Answer (score 0):

```
public PartialViewResult Editar(int id)
{
    var context = new Entities();
    int codEps = GetUsuarioLogado().CodEmpresa;

    if (id == 0) return PartialView(new FORMATO()
    {
        ATIVO = false
    });

    var formato = context.FORMATO.Where(f => f.COD_EPS == codEps && f.COD_FORMATO == id).FirstOrDefault();

    return PartialView(formato != null ? formato : new FORMATO()
    {
        ATIVO = false
    });
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult Editar(FORMATO formato)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("NOME", "Erro");
    return PartialView(formato);
}
```

O código JS pra abrir o modal de edição é esse:

```
function CarregarModalFormatoEdit(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Editar", "Formatos", null)',
        data: { id },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#modalEditWrapper').html(response);
            $('#modalFormatoEdit').modal('show');
        }
    });
}
```

A ideia do JS é apenas popular o retorno da PartialView dentro do modal-body e exibir o mesmo. As operações de update, insert e delete ficariam dentro da própria PartialView e Controller.